# How to sort data according to days of the week?

Tags: python, sorting

I have made a program that takes input temperature of seven days of the week and convert them into Fahrenheit and prints average, maximum and minimum temperature of the week. I have bubble sorted them in ascending order where i want to sort them as days of the week like Sunday, Monday ......

So, here is the code:

```
# Program: SA_7dayThermometer.py
# Date: May 26, 2022
# Author: Sarthak Amgain (Student #1095783)
# Description: Calculates the entered temperature into farenheight and also finds highest, lowest and average temperature of the week
# This is a solution to coding assignment #2.

print("The 7-Day Thermometer Program") #Printing the program description 

print("")
print("")

days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"] #defining days list
temperature = [] #defining a blank list 
highest = float(0.0)
lowest = float(100.0)
total = float(0.0)  

for i in range(7): #Initializing loop
    inp = round(float(input("Please enter the temperature for " + days[i] + " in Celsius: ")),1) #Taking input from the user 
    temperature.append(inp) #adding the input to the blank list 
    


print("")
print("")
    
print("You entered these Temperatures in Celsius and Fahrenheit.")

print("")
print("")


for j in range(len(temperature)):
    #================= Bubble sorting =================
    def bubble_sort(arr):
        for a in range(len(arr)):
            for b in range(len(arr)-1):
                if(arr[b]>arr[b+1]):
                    temp=arr[b]
                    arr[b]=arr[b+1]
                    arr[b+1]=temp
        return arr
    #===================================================
    #Printing the temperature in celcius and farenheit in ascending order
    sort = bubble_sort(temperature)
    Fahrenheit = round(((temperature[j] * 1.8) + 32),1)
    total = total + temperature[j]
    print(str(sort[j]) + " C° is " + str(Fahrenheit) + " F°" )
    
print("--------------------")
avg = round(total / len(temperature),1) #Calculating the average temperature
print("High Temp: " + str(max(temperature)) + " C°, Low Temp: " + str(min(temperature)) + " C° and Average Temp: " + str(avg) + " C°")#Printing the highest, lowest, and average temperature.
```

Comment: Why do you not use the native `sort` method, and why do you sort the same list multiple times?

Comment: 1) Why is your function definition (bubble_sort) in a for loop, and 2) is there a reason you're not using the built-in sort function?

Comment: your list `temperature` has only temperatures - how do you want to sort it by day of week.? But it seems you already have it in correct order. You ask for data in order `Sunday`, `Monday`, etc. so your data in `temperatures` are already in order `Sunday`, `Monday`, etc.

Comment: `total = sum(temperature)` - without `for`-loop

Answer (score 0):

first, I suggest you create a correlation between the days and the temperature using a dictionary.
example:

```
days = {'M':22, 'T':34, 'W':18}
print(max(days), days[max(days)]) #Max temp
print(min(days), days[min(days)]) #Min temp
```

By doing this you can sort by the days of the week. You also reduce your code and have a lot better organization.
Learn more about [dict](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)